# Test with MockWebServer never finishes

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, mockito

I have a class which implements CommandLineRunner and in its run method a webClient makes a request and does some processing with the response, including a method that I want to verify in a test:

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class WowGreatClass implements CommandLineRunner {
    private final WebClient webClient;

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) {
        webClient.get()
            .uri("/foo")
            .retrieve()
            .bodyToMono(PairsResponseDto.class)
            .flatMap(response -> Flux.fromIterable(response.getResult()))
            .collectList()
            .map(this::methodToTest)
            //...
        ).block(); 
    }
}
```

So I am using a MockWebServer in the test like so:

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class WowGreatTest {

    MockWebServer mockServer = new MockWebServer();

    @Spy
    WowGreatClass greatClass = new WowGreatClass(WebClient.create(mockServer.url("/").toString()));

    @Captor
    ArgumentCaptor<String> captor;

    @Test
    public void testTheThing() {
        mockServer.enqueue(
            new MockResponse()
                .setResponseCode(200)
                .addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
                .setBody("something really interesting"));

        greatClass.run();
        verify(greatClass).methodToTest(captor.capture());
    }
}
```

The MockWebServer does what it should during the test, the issue is that after the initial request it seems to just hang forever waiting for more. The `run()` method never finishes and the `verify()` call is never reached. Am I missing something obvious here, or what's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

MockServer.url("/") return something like this:
`http://kubernetes.docker.internal:49954/`
so when you pass this to WebClient in run method your url looks like:
`http://kubernetes.docker.internal:49954//foo` with `//` beacause of `.uri("/foo")` in your WebClient builder.

Instead of `mockServer.url("/").toString()` just use `"http://localhost:" + mockServer.getPort()`